# Runtime value in forRoot of Angular Module

Tags: javascript, angular, module

In my angular app there is this module called [Ngx-Stripe](https://github.com/richnologies/ngx-stripe)

I have defined it as documentation like following:

```
NgxStripeModule.forRoot('***your-stripe-publishable key***');
```

But the problem is I don't get this key on app bootstrap, I am not supposed to hardcode it in angular `app.module` or global like in `index.html` when I am using stripe withput any angular library.

I am getting this key on the api call after user proceeds to payment page. How can I define this key in this scenario ?

Comment: Was trying to achieve this some time ago... Unfortunately I was forced to set the data in a webpack or <script> in index.html before Angular's sources

Comment: HI @DanielKucal, I also tried within index.html, for that matter I dont even need ngx-stripe, I am able to do things just like that but is this not possible right or what is the scene like ?

Comment: I will try to explain it in an answer

Comment: @Rakeschand if you're interested in a better way of doing this as Samber suggested in another comment, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73432312/2435473)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wish it'd be straightforward, but the only way I was able to achieve it was something like:

**index.html** (alternatively webpack-injected script), has to be placed before Angular's sources:

```
<script>
  var STRIPE_KEY = 'paste it here';
</script>
```

**app.module.ts**:

```
declare var STRIPE_KEY;

// ...
NgxStripeModule.forRoot(STRIPE_KEY);
```

The problem here is `.forRoot()` has to be statically-analyzed by Angular AoT compiler, so it can't accept what you want it to accept... How about setting the key after you got it via `StripeService.changeKey(key: string)` method?

Comment: I understood that, but my requirement is something else. Let’s see if I can do that.

Comment: How about passing empty key at the beginning and then setting it by `StripeService.changeKey()` method in this case?

Comment: FYI, `stripeService.changeKey()` is only available in `@nomadreservations/ngx-stripe` fork.

Answer (score 1):

Simply import StripeService from ngx-stripe and call changeKey on that service once you have your key.

Answer (score 0):

For lazy loading your Stripe config key you can create your own instance of StripeService using StripeFactory that is available from ngx-stripe.

Check the documentation here for a full explanation:

https://richnologies.gitbook.io/ngx-stripe/core-concepts/service-factory