# How to add dynamic value in AppNgModule forRoot()?

Tags: angular, stripe-payments

I have searched a lot but didn't find any solution yet.

```
NgxStripeModule.forRoot('publishable_key'),
```

***I need this "publishable_key" should be dynamic and it will come from a REST API.***

Is there any option to do that?

Thank you.

Comment: does your `NgxStripeModule` contains `Routes` ? can you provide your `NgxStripeModule`?

Answer (score 3):

You first have to register the module with the `forRoot` method as a blank string `NgxStripeModule.forRoot('')`. Later using [**`APP_INITIALIZER`**](https://angular.io/api/core/APP_INITIALIZER) make an API call, receive a settings, extract `publishable_key` and fill in that in strip API using `stripeService.changeKey('publishable_key') method.` This process will happen before the app bootstrap. So no need to worry about picking up right settings.

```
function initializeApp(http: HttpClient, stripeService: StripeService): Observable<any> {
  return http.get('api/url').pipe(
    tap((data) => stripeService.changeKey(data.publishable_key)) // or .setKey(...)
  );
}
@NgModule({
 imports: [
   ...,
   NgxStripeModule.forRoot(''),
 ],
 declarations: [...],
 bootstrap: [AppComponent],
 providers: [
  ...,
  {
   provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
   useFactory: initializeApp,
   multi: true,
   deps: [HttpClient, StripeService]
  }
 ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```